# ReactJS - onClick doesn't work in raw javascripts

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, frameworks, frontend, reactjs

As the title suggests.

I want to trigger an event by clicking the element.

In JSX, onClick works well, but somehow it just dead in raw JavaScript.

```
React.DOM.button({ type: 'button' }, { onClick: this.handleClick }, 'js button')
```

What may be the issue?

[see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wBYHY/8/)

Comment: problem solved!

syntax should be `React.DOM.button({ type: 'button' , onClick: this.handleClick }, 'js button')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your key-value pairs should be in one object, as the first argument. The rest of the arguments are for children.

```
React.DOM.button({ type: 'button', onClick: this.handleClick }, 'js button');
```